# Symfony task: displaying colored text in the output (command line)?

Tags: symfony1, colors, task, command-line-interface

I would like to have a very basic formatting (just colors) on the text displayed by a Symfony task in the command line output (just like the colors you see when running tests): any idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Symfony 1.x or Symfony2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your task you may use two functions, both with a $style parameter, to generate an output :

- [logBlock()](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfTask#method_logblock) - print a (colored) *whole* text
- [logSection()](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfTask#method_logsection) - print a (colored) section with an additional text

And here you can find [Symfony's documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/13-Leveraging-the-Power-of-the-Command-Line#chapter_13_helper_methods_logging).

Comment: You can specify the color by using the basic formatting style provided (`ERROR`, `INFO`, `COMMENT` e `QUESTION`)

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like:

```
echo "\033[01;31m Show me some red colors \033[0m";
```

More colors here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of the Symfony terminal output by changing the file:

`/lib/symfony/vendor/phing/listener/AnsiColorLogger.php`

At the constructor method you can change the color of each type of output (info, error, debug...):

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->errColor = self::PREFIX . self::ATTR_DIM . self::SEPARATOR . self::FG_RED . self::SUFFIX;
    $this->warnColor = self::PREFIX . self::ATTR_DIM . self::SEPARATOR . self::FG_MAGENTA . self::SUFFIX;
    $this->infoColor = self::PREFIX . self::ATTR_DIM . self::SEPARATOR . self::FG_GREEN . self::SUFFIX;
    $this->verboseColor = self::PREFIX . self::ATTR_DIM . self::SEPARATOR . self::FG_CYAN . self::SUFFIX;
    $this->debugColor = self::PREFIX . self::ATTR_DIM . self::SEPARATOR . self::FG_BLUE . self::SUFFIX;
}
```

You have a limited range of colors but it may help you.